# Eigen Rotation2D applied to a 2-vector

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, rotation, eigen

I have searched the internet and read Eigen tutorial, and all about transformations, rotations but I cannot figure how to apply a rotation to a 2-vector. Usually is a matrix-vector product.
I'm using Visual studio 2010. Windows 7. Here is my code

```
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <Eigen/Geometry> 

using namespace std;
using Eigen::VectorXd;
using Eigen::VectorXf;
using Eigen::Vector2d;
using Eigen::Vector2f;
using Eigen::Rotation2Df;

int main(){  
   Vector2f v;  
   v << 100.0f,200.0f;  
   cout << "\nthe initial vector is v = \n" << endl << v << endl << endl; 
   float theta = M_PI/4;
   //Eigen::AffineCompact2d t;
   Rotation2Df t(theta);
   t.toRotationMatrix();
   printf ("\nUsing an Affine2f\n");
   cout <<"\nthe rotation Matrix is \n"<< t.matrix() << std::endl;
   Vector2f rotatedVect = t*v.transpose();
   cout <<"the rotated vector is \n"<< rotatedVect << std::endl;

   std::cin.get();
}
```

The problem is in this line:

```
Vector2f rotatedVect = t*v.transpose();
```

It is like it is confused which multiplication operator need to use. If concatenation or matrix-vector multiplication.  I like this library but at this point I am seriously rethinking using it in my project. This is the error that visual studio 2010 generates when I run the code. I would appreciate any help!

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: GettingStarted, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>Build started 5/25/2016 12:52:03 PM.
1>_PrepareForClean:
1>  Deleting file "x64\Debug\GettingStarted.lastbuildstate".
1>InitializeBuildStatus:
1>  Creating "x64\Debug\GettingStarted.unsuccessfulbuild" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
1>ClCompile:
1>  firstprog.cpp
1>firstprog.cpp(18): warning C4305: 'initializing' : truncation from 'double' to 'float'
1>firstprog.cpp(24): error C2666: 'Eigen::Rotation2D<_Scalar>::operator *' : 2 overloads have similar conversions
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Scalar=float
1>          ]
1>          c:\users\maider\eigen\src/Geometry/Rotation2D.h(85): could be 'Eigen::Matrix<_Scalar,_Rows,_Cols> Eigen::Rotation2D<_Scalar>::operator *(const Eigen::Matrix<_Scalar,_Rows,_Cols> &) const'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Scalar=float,
1>              _Rows=2,
1>              _Cols=1
1>          ]
1>          c:\users\maider\eigen\src/Geometry/RotationBase.h(71): or       'Eigen::Matrix<_Scalar,_Rows,_Cols> Eigen::RotationBase<Derived,_Dim>::operator *<Eigen::Transpose<MatrixType>>(const Eigen::EigenBase<Eigen::Transpose<MatrixType>> &) const'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Scalar=float,
1>              _Rows=2,
1>              _Cols=1,
1>              Derived=Eigen::Rotation2D<float>,
1>              _Dim=2,
1>              MatrixType=Eigen::Matrix<float,2,1>
1>          ]
1>          while trying to match the argument list '(Eigen::Rotation2Df, Eigen::Transpose<MatrixType>)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              MatrixType=Eigen::Matrix<float,2,1>
1>          ]
1>
1>Build FAILED.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:01.02
========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Answer (score 4):

First check the version of Eigen, looks like there is a problem with the overload of the operator* for versions 3.2.3 and less. Please see https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=74&t=124235&p=326983&hilit=Rotation2D#p326983
But after I downloaded the latest version and re-run my code using

```
Vector2f rotatedVect = t.toRotationMatrix()*v;
```

It worked!